# Overriding equals in linked list

Tags: java, list, linked-list

Been searching for a solution to my problem. Been reading a lot about overriding equals to properly compare nodes of a linked list but have become stuck. Basically I am trying to search through my list and find a node that equals it and delete it. I have found the way to look through the linked list but when I return the node it is just gibberish. I am trying to find a way to get it into a string and compare it to another string. Anyway here is the code and my equals method that currently does not work.

```
public class MagazineList {
    private MagazineNode list;
    private Object obj;

    public MagazineList(){
        list = null;
    }


    public void add(Magazine mag){
        MagazineNode node = new MagazineNode(mag);
        MagazineNode current;

        if(list==null)
            list = node;
        else{
            current = list;
            while(current.next != null)
                current = current.next;
            current.next = node;
        }   
    }
    public void insert(Magazine mag)
    {
        MagazineNode node = new MagazineNode (mag);

        // make the new first node point to the current root
        node.next=list;

        // update the root to the new first node
        list=node;
    }
    public void deleteAll(){
        if(list == null){

        }
        else{
            list = null;
        }
    }

    public void delete (Magazine mag) {
        MagazineNode current = this.list;
        MagazineNode before;

        //if is the first element
        if (current.equals(mag)) {
            this.list = current.next;
            return;     //ending the method
        }


        before = current;

        //while there are elements in the list
        while ((current = current.next) != null) {

            //if is the current element
            if (current.equals(mag)) {
                before.next = current.next;
                return;     //endind the method 
            }

            before = current;
        }

        //it isnt in the list
    }
    public boolean equals(Object other) {

        System.out.println("Here in equals" + other + this);
        // Not strictly necessary, but often a good optimization
        if (this == other)
            return true;
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    @ Override
    public String toString(){
        String result = " ";

        MagazineNode current = list;
        while (current != null){
            result += current.magazine + "\n";
            current = current.next;     
        }
        return result;
    }


    private class MagazineNode {
        public Magazine magazine;
        public MagazineNode next;


        public MagazineNode(Magazine mag){
            magazine = mag;
            next = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using one of the linked list implementations available in the java api?

Comment: Yes not allowed to. It is for computer science class and they are trying to show us what the API is able to do for us and say that we need to know the long way before the short way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your delete method looks fine, except you shouldn't compare a MagazineNode with a Magazine. You should compare a Magazine with a Magazine.

Replace `if (current.equals(mag))` by `if (current.magazine.equals(mag))`.

Comment: I do this and the output is identical but it is still returning false it doesnt make any sense why this is happening it is identical output

Comment: What is returning false? delete() returns void. How could it return false? You're talking about an output, but the output of what? What method are you calling, with which arguments, and on a list containing what? What's the result? How is Magazine.equals() defined?

Comment: I am using print to find out whats going on in the program and it is printing false. I haven’t defined equals rather just used the pre defined version of it.  The list just contains strings and I can enter the same string and it still returns false

Comment: The dafault version of equals only returns true if the two compared objects are exactly the same instance. Your list doesn't contain String instance, but Magazine instances. If you want one magazine to be equal to another Magazine if it contains the same string, then you need to override equals in the Magazine class.

Answer (score 1):

Ok - note that your equals method is just re-implementing the == identity equals.

that means if `other` is not the same Magazine object, this will fail. if that's how you want it that's fine, but normally you want to choose the attributes within Magazine.

So if Magazine has a `String title`, in your equals method you'd do something like:

```
if (magazine instanceof Magazine && magazine.getTitle().equals(other.getTitle()) returnval = true;
```

also, see Joshua Bloch's Effective Java for a great description of this. Any time you override the equals method, you want to also override the hashCode method. They go together and he describes why.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipse, use this function: Eclipse -> Source -> Generate hashCode() and equals(). And study its implementation. That would help you understand how equals() and hashCode() should be written. Good luck.

Comment: Honestly that was super helpful. It was very difficult and abstract to understand but looking at it makes sense